# Will Xcode 5 run on yosemite?

Tags: xcode, ios7, osx-yosemite

I upgraded to Yosemite and now Xcode 5 Beta 3 won't run (at all). Is that because it is a beta version? If so, should I install a full release, or go to Xcode 6? I have just been finishing off changes to an iOS 7 app which I wan to submit soon.
EDIT: Tried to install full version of 5.1 but is says it is not compatible with OS. 
Downloading Xcode 6 at the moment - will take hours.
Will I be able to use Xcode 6 to finish and publish the upgrade of the 7.1 app, or should I go back to Mavericks?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is not enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: the answer is no - at least for me...creating an outlet crashes it...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot submit anything built with beta SDKs, so you will need to update to xCode 5.1.1 either way. It should work on Yosemite, but I wouldn't recommend installing it if you're working on something you want to submit.